# Having minimum mousedown time on control

Tags: c#, mousedown

I have a control (basically an ON/OFF toggle switch) which I want the user to press for at least one second before switching states. I can measure the time between the mouse down and mouse up events on the control and make sure the mouse never leaves the control while down, but wanted to know:

Is there was a better method of establishing that the "click" on that control satisfies a minimum time?

Comment: Your solution seems reasonable to me.  I don't think there's any built in mechanism for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simpler way, you must do the steps you have described.

But, this "behavior" can be implemented in a general way - so it can be reused multiple times.

Here is an example of such implementation:

```
public class LongClick
{
    public static void Attach(Control Control, EventHandler Handler)
    {
        var LC = new LongClick { Control = Control, Handler = Handler };
        Control.MouseDown += LC.ControlOnMouseDown;
        Control.MouseMove += LC.ControlOnMouseMove;
        Control.MouseUp += LC.ControlOnMouseUp;
    }

    private Control Control;
    public EventHandler Handler;
    private DateTime? MDS;

    private void ControlOnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) MDS = DateTime.Now;
    }
    private void ControlOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MDS == null) return;
        if (e.X < 0) MDS = null;
        if (e.X > Control.Width) MDS = null;
        if (e.Y < 0) MDS = null;
        if (e.Y > Control.Height) MDS = null;
    }
    private void ControlOnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MDS == null) return;
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
        var TimePassed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(MDS.Value);
        MDS = null;
        if (TimePassed.TotalSeconds < 1) return;
        if (Handler == null) return;
        Handler(Control, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And the usage is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LongClick.Attach(button1, button1_LongClick);
}

private void button1_LongClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("button1 long clicked!");
}
```

There are other variations of the implementation, one of them would be to override the control class (it is even simpler than this one).